# select taking 20 seconds? if I remove order by it will take only 0,020

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this select:

```
select c.user, p.user, p.title, cm.user, cm.block, pp.foto from members cm
left join topics p on cm.member = p.id
left join profile_picture pp on pp.user = cm.user
left join cadastro c on cm.user = c.id
where cm.member = 1 and ((p.user = 10) or ((p.user != 10) and (cm.block = 0)))
group by cm.user
order by cm.block desc, cm.data desc
limit 0,100
```

explain without order by:
[image]

explain with order by:

[image]

```
`members` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `member` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20),
  `block` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY (`user`, `member`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `member_block` ( `member`, `block`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES cadastro (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`member`) REFERENCES topics (`id`)
)

and topics

`topics` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(40),
  `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(400),
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20),
  `privado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES cadastro (`id`)
)
```

I tried a index on cm.block and cm.data but no success. any ideas?

Comment: Invalid group by. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh Is it possible for the group by clause to cause this huge difference?

Comment: @revo, I don't know. I'd start with correcting the query anyway, and then see if the performance problem still remains.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for your answer. but how would it be? can you give me an example?

Comment: @jarlh without the group by took 0.0252 seconds! but I don't know if the result is the same as I'd like to get.

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Comment: @jarlh to sum up, the members who join a topic. but show first the ones with block = 1. it will only show members with block = 1 to topic owner (who created the topic).